# Sample Mean of Correlated/Dependent Random Variables...

Tags: random-variables, correlation, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $\bar{U}$ and $\bar{V}$ are sample means from a highly correlated or highly dependent random process (e.g., waiting times from a queueing process)

That is, let
$$
\bar{U} = \frac{1}{n}\left(X_1+ X_2+ \dots+ X_n \right)
$$
and
$$
\bar{V} = \frac{1}{m}\left(X_1+ X_2+ \dots+ X_m \right)
$$
where $m \gg n$; that is $m$ is much larger than $n$ ($m$ could be infinite),

$\bf{QUESTION:}$Is it the case, in general, that $\bar{U} < \bar{V}$? (since $n < m$).

I have simulated the process and
$\bar{U} < \bar{V}$ appears to be the true.

I have no idea how to show this analytically/mathematically...

Comment: The highest correlation we have when all the $X_i$'s are identical. Then $\bar{U}=\bar{V}$. Can you describe in more detail what exactly you have simulated?

Comment: You can get the symbol $\gg$ using `\gg`.

Comment: I have simulated waiting (or response) times from an M/M/1 queue during a busy period ($\bar{U}$) and compared them to the steady-state response times $(\bar{V})$. From my simulations, it (always) appears that the response times from the busy period (on average) is less than or equal to that of the steady-state - especially as utilization of the server gets high (i.e., $\rho > 0.5$).

Comment: My thought was that since there are a finite number of samples of $\bar{U}$, then as long as $\rho < 1$, the busy period will always end. Consequently, this would imply that  $\bar{V}$ > $\bar{U}$ since this deals with many more samples (possibly infinite) since it is the steady-state result as $n \rightarrow \infty$. That is $\bar{U}$ does not have "enough" samples to converge to the true mean, whereas $\bar{V}$ does.